# Select Carregando sem dados AJAX

Tags: ajax

Tenho ajax, que esta vindo com os dados em branco, como vcs poder ver nas imagens abaixo, esta chegando os dados, só que na hora de carregar no select, o value, e text, ficam em branco

```js
<script>
    $("#UF").on("change", function() {
       
        var url = '@Url.Action("BuscaCidades", "CidadeG", new {area = "Gerencial"})';
        var estado = $("#UF option:selected").val();
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: { estado: estado },
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (cidade) {
                debugger;
                if (cidade != null) {
                    var selectbox = $('#cbmunicipio');
                    $("#cbmunicipio").empty();
                    $('<option>').val("0").text("Selecione o Município").appendTo(selectbox);
                    $.each(cidade.cidade,
                        function(i, d) {
                            $('<option>').val(d.id).text(d.value).appendTo(selectbox);
                        });


                }
            },
            error: function(ex) {
                //alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

```html
   <select id="cbmunicipio" class="form-control">
                                               
    </select>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a estrutura desse objeto que você recebe por AJAX? O seu `select` parece ter várias opções, essas opções só estão em branco. Tem certeza que o nome das cidades estão em `d.value`?

Comment: vou por mais uma imagem.. só um momento... não entendo muito de ajax, me basiei por esse questão aqui [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/347779/carregar-select-de-cidade-ap%C3%B3s-selecionar-estado)

Comment: A propriedade `Value` começa com um v maiúsculo, substitua `d.value` por `d.Value`. Faça o mesmo com `Id`.

Comment: Putz... era só isso msm!!!!!!

Comment: coloca como resposta, que eu aceito como correta!

Comment: Isso é só um erro de digitação, se não me engano essas perguntas geralmente são fechadas, visto que ela dificilmente irá servir de referência para outro usuário.